# AWS Lambda Function is returning Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Consider following code -

```
function index(event, context, callback) {
  //some code
}
exports.handler = index();

{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'"
}
```

This is my function which is having business logic. My javascript file name is `index.js`.

Whenever I test this code on aws lambda, It gives following `log(failed)`.

This is a screenshot of the Amazon Lambda Upload Site:
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In `export.handler`, you are not referencing the `index` function, but the result of its execution. I guess you want to export the function itself.

```
let index = function index(event, context, callback) {
  //some code
}
exports.handler = index;
```

Or maybe directly

```
exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is to declare your function as the exports.handler. When your function exports to lambda, it comes with the namespace.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    //code
}
```

You can ignore the callback if you want fast code.

Answer (score 3):

You may have incorrectly specified your handler as "index.js" instead of "index.handler"