# AWS Lambda Python: 'handler' missing on module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a deployment package in the following structure:

```
my-project.zip
    --- my-project.py
    ------ lambda_handler()
```

Then I define the handler path in configuration file

my-project.lambda_handler

Get the error:

```
'handler' missing on module
```

Can not understand that

Comment: Can you try without using the dash character in your filename?

Comment: @Leon thanks for the comment, the same error if I try without using the dash character

Comment: For others, it might be possible that the filename is somehow invalid. I had to change my filename from `token.py` to `tokens.py` and then update the handler to fix this error.

Answer (score 15):

There are some issues occurring this error.

### Issue#1:

The very first issue you’re gonna run into is if you name the file incorrectly, you get this error:

Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named lambda_function

If you name the function incorrectly you get this error:

> Handler 'handler' missing on module 'lambda_function_file': 'module'
>   object has no attribute 'handler'

On the dashboard, make sure the handler field is entered as `function_filename.actual_function_name` and make sure they match up in your deployment package.

If only the messages were a bit more instructive that would have been a simpler step.

### Resource Link:

[**No lambda_function?**](http://www.iheavy.com/2016/02/14/getting-errors-building-amazon-lambda-python-functions-help-howto/)

### Issue#2:

[adrian_praja](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=259173) has solved the issue in [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=599109). He answered the following

> I belive your `index.js` should contain
>
> ```
> exports.createThumbnailHandler = function(event, context) {}
> ```

### Issue#3:

Solution: Correctly specify the method call

This happens when the specification of the method called by `node.js` is incorrect in Lambda's setting.
Please review the specification of the method to call.

In the case of the above error message, I attempted to call the handler method of `index.js`, but the corresponding method could not be found.
The processing to call is set with "Handler" on the configuration tab.
Below is an example of setting to call the handler method of `index.js`.
[image]

### Resource Link:

1. http://qiita.com/kazuqqfp/items/ac8d93918d0030b31aad
2. [AWS Lambda Function is returning Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117274/aws-lambda-function-is-returning-handler-handler-missing-on-module-index)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and had to make sure I had a function called `handler` in my file, e.g.:

```
# this just takes whatever is sent to the api gateway and sends it back

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        return response(event, 200)
    except Exception as e:
        return response('Error' + e.message, 400)

def response(message, status_code):
    return message
```

Answer (score 0):

While not specific to your provided example, this error can occur for another reason as well -- naming conflicts with standard library modules.

E.g. if I have the following package structure, and specify my handler as `email.handler`, there will be a collision with the standard library [`email` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) and a similar error will be raised: `handler missing on module 'email'`

```
my-project.zip
    --- email.py
    ------ handler()
```