# Missing handler error in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My apologies for basic question. I am completely new to AWS as well as Python. I am trying to do sample code given in https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#accessing-a-bucket but facing a error.

```
import botocore
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
exists = True


try:
    s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='bucketname')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    # If a client error is thrown, then check that it was a 404 error.
    # If it was a 404 error, then the bucket does not exist.
    error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
    if error_code == 404:
        exists = False
```

Error in logs is

> "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module
>   'lambda_function'"

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741822/aws-lambda-python-handler-missing-on-module

Comment: @halfer understood.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to define a function in your code. The code is missing the function named `lambda_handler`. Your code should look like:

```
    import botocore
    import boto3

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
        exists = True

        try:
            s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='bucketname')
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            # If a client error is thrown, then check that it was a 404 error.
            # If it was a 404 error, then the bucket does not exist.
            error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
            if error_code == 404:
                exists = False
```

Answer (score 6):

Move your code inside a python function. You can give it any name but that will become your handler. Go to lambda function basic settings and change the default handler to `<yourfilename>_<yourfunctionname>`. By default when you create a lambda function, the file name will be `lambda_function_name.py` (you can change it) and your handler method will be `lambda_handler` (you can change it), so the entry point is `lambda_function_name.lambda_handler`.

Answer (score -6):

Kishna_mee2004 is right you need to define `lambda_handler` without this it never work but if you getting below error:

> Handler 'py' missing on module 'jobdata_rdcmedia_s3_Etl_job_scheduler_lambda': 'module' object has no attribute 'py'

Then you need to check handler info whether you have mention `lambda_function_name.lambda_handler` or not.