# "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Below is my code and error I am getting.. I need help.

```
import boto3

    ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_client.create_tags(Resources=['i-01d90bb1c3a45708b'], Tags=[{'Key':'Testing', 'Value':'TestingBySwamy'}])
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"
}
Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function': module 'lambda_function' has no attribute 'lambda_handler'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing handler error in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266106/missing-handler-error-in-aws-lambda)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266106/missing-handler-error-in-aws-lambda/48266238
Try putting your code under a function named lambda_handler

Answer (score 4):

When you run the code in the lambda, it has the following syntax,

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    // paste your code here
    return some_value
```

In your case, try the following,

```
import boto3

def handler_name(event, context): 
    ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_client.create_tags(Resources=['i-01d90bb1c3a45708b'], Tags=[{'Key':'Testing', 'Value':'TestingBySwamy'}])
```

Refer: [Lambda Function Handler (Python) - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html)