# AWS Lambda error 'lambda_handler' missing on module, but function seems to exist

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function. The filename in the AWS console "Code source" area is called `lambda_function.py`. Within this file is code with a defined `lambda_handler` function, as per below:

**lambda_function.py**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("hello world")
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Cheers from AWS Lambda!!')
    }
```

I have ensured to select File > Save.

If I click "Test," the Execution results tab shows an error:

```
Test Event Name
hello_world

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "requestId": "f6a5ce69-aa3a-4c27-877f-e00e4c77279b",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: f6a5ce69-aa3a-4c27-877f-e00e4c77279b Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.HandlerNotFound: Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: f6a5ce69-aa3a-4c27-877f-e00e4c77279b
REPORT RequestId: f6a5ce69-aa3a-4c27-877f-e00e4c77279b  Duration: 1.21 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB

Request ID
f6a5ce69-aa3a-4c27-877f-e00e4c77279b
```

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266106/missing-handler-error-in-aws-lambda) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790789/handler-lambda-handler-missing-on-module-lambda-function) answers for this exact issue, and they all recommend ensuring that the filename and function match that defined within "Runtime settings > Handler." I have ensured this:

[image: screenshot of the Handler area of Runtime Settings]

Here is the Handler name copied and pasted, to check spelling:

```
lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

**Why is AWS Lambda unable to find the handler function in my Lambda?**

Comment: Did you perhaps just change the function name and forgot to deploy the changes?

Comment: Oh you have to click deploy as well?? -.-